# Compiling bitcoin-core from source Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: bitcoind, compiling

Hey everything has usually been fine compiling from source until i updated to Ubuntu 17.10

I've configured using --disable-wallet and i'm using the most up to date master branch

```
chris@chris-GE60-2PL:~/bitcoin$ sudo make
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chris/bitcoin/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/chris/bitcoin/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/chris/bitcoin'
cd . && /bin/bash ./config.status src/config/bitcoin-config.h
config.status: creating src/config/bitcoin-config.h
config.status: src/config/bitcoin-config.h is unchanged
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/chris/bitcoin'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/chris/bitcoin'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/chris/bitcoin'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/chris/bitcoin/src/secp256k1'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/chris/bitcoin/src/secp256k1'
  CXX      libbitcoin_util_a-clientversion.o
  AR       libbitcoin_util.a
  CXXLD    bitcoind
  CXXLD    bitcoin-cli
  CXXLD    bitcoin-tx
  CXXLD    test/test_bitcoin
  CXXLD    bench/bench_bitcoin
  CXX      qt/qt_libbitcoinqt_a-moc_bitcoingui.o
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp: In static member function ‘static void 
BitcoinGUI::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, 
void**)’:
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:217:21: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘setEncryptionStatus’; did you mean ‘setDockOptions’?
         case 6: _t->setEncryptionStatus((*reinterpret_cast< int(*)>
(_a[1]))); break;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     setDockOptions
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:218:21: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘setHDStatus’; did you mean ‘setStatusBar’?
         case 7: _t->setHDStatus((*reinterpret_cast< int(*)>(_a[1]))); 
break;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
                     setStatusBar
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:219:33: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘handlePaymentRequest’
         case 8: { bool _r = _t-
>handlePaymentRequest((*reinterpret_cast< const SendCoinsRecipient(*)>
(_a[1])));
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:221:21: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘incomingTransaction’
         case 9: _t->incomingTransaction((*reinterpret_cast< const 
QString(*)>(_a[1])),(*reinterpret_cast< int(*)>(_a[2])),
(*reinterpret_cast< const CAmount(*)>(_a[3])),(*reinterpret_cast< 
const QString(*)>(_a[4])),(*reinterpret_cast< const QString(*)>
(_a[5])),(*reinterpret_cast< const QString(*)>(_a[6]))); break;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:222:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘gotoOverviewPage’
         case 10: _t->gotoOverviewPage(); break;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:223:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘gotoHistoryPage’
         case 11: _t->gotoHistoryPage(); break;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:224:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘gotoReceiveCoinsPage’
         case 12: _t->gotoReceiveCoinsPage(); break;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:225:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘gotoSendCoinsPage’
         case 13: _t->gotoSendCoinsPage((*reinterpret_cast< 
QString(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:226:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘gotoSendCoinsPage’
        case 14: _t->gotoSendCoinsPage(); break;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:227:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘gotoSignMessageTab’
         case 15: _t->gotoSignMessageTab((*reinterpret_cast< 
QString(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:228:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘gotoSignMessageTab’
         case 16: _t->gotoSignMessageTab(); break;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:229:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘gotoVerifyMessageTab’
         case 17: _t->gotoVerifyMessageTab((*reinterpret_cast< 
QString(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:230:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member 
named ‘gotoVerifyMessageTab’
         case 18: _t->gotoVerifyMessageTab(); break;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qt/moc_bitcoingui.cpp:231:22: error: ‘class BitcoinGUI’ has no member named ‘openClicked’; did you mean ‘optionsClicked’?
     case 19: _t->openClicked(); break;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
                      optionsClicked
Makefile:7129: recipe for target 'qt/qt_libbitcoinqt_a-moc_bitcoingui.o' 
failed
make[2]: *** [qt/qt_libbitcoinqt_a-moc_bitcoingui.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/chris/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:9361: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chris/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:746: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you're asking... is it how to fix the error?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Can you please state what platform you are compiling for?

Answer (score 2):

Do `make clean` then rebuild.

If that doesn't work, reconfigure (`./autogen.sh` and `./configure`) then `make clean` again, then `make`.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually better to build a tagged version than from just off the top of master which may have additional changes.

More recently there were some dependancy changes<sup>[[1](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12515#issuecomment-368283657)]</sup>.

In the `/bitcoin` directory you need to:

```
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev
git clean -fdx
```

Get on the master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Pull down the current master including tags. Depending on how you are configured, how to do this will vary but could be as simple as `git pull origin --tags`

Then, you should definitely check out a tagged version. The current highest tagged version as of writing is v0.16.0 - you can check what tags exist with `git tag` - I usually do that this way into a branch:

```
git checkout v0.16.0 -b v016
```

Then, follow the specific build instructions in `/bitcoin/doc/*.md`. For example, Ubuntu 17.04 is specifically supported in `build-unix.md`

rel:
[[1](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12515#issuecomment-368283657)] github.com - "Ok, I've identified the issue. It is because one of the dependencies ..." - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12515#issuecomment-368283657